# Bootstrap 5 - Modal not showing up

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, modal-dialog, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to open a modal when an image is clicked with this code here:

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

That's the original code from [Bootstrap Modal Doc](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/)
But yet got it to work, I click the button and nothing happens

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May be you missed some bootstrap dependency.

Here is the working full code demo:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">        
        
    </head>

    <body>
    
        <!-- Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->

        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>  

        <!-- Dialog demo -->  
                
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModalLive">
            Launch demo modal
        </button>

        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLive" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLiveLabel" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLiveLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Woohoo, you're reading this text in a modal!</p>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks that actually working!
But where did you find the head <link> AND the <script> tags that you mentioned??
Because I didn't find those inside the Modal page in Bootstrap 5 Docs

Comment: I found them here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/ . Please flag my answer as resolution and upvote it if you want.